# Flutter web Navigator forward button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

**My problem**

This problem is about Flutter web's navigation. When working with the *onGenerateRoute* function, the navigation on the web is "near" the vanilla experience. We can pop route with the back button of the browser, push a new route and get those routes' names in the URL. But my problem resides in the forward button:

- When going back on the browser, we can't go forward afterward. (not that bad)
- When you enter a URL for a route manually, we go on this route, but the forward button is enabled, and when click, another same route is pushed in the route stack. (The biggest problem)

**Demonstration**

https://youtu.be/CZB1UDsB8mE

In this video, I show my project navigation and after 0:26 the problem I have

**Code to reproduce**

I have written a simple project to demonstrate my problem.

GitHub: https://github.com/NeroThroN/navigator

**Solution**

Does someone have the solution to include and fix the forward button in Flutter or a way to disable the forward button completely in the browser?

Comment: Your app is using the Navigator 1 API. For advanced routing requirements you should use the Navigator 2 API. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32248#issuecomment-822607461